# React Native navigation.navigate params not updating

Tags: javascript, react-native

I try to navigate from home screen to detail screen using navigation.navigate(). When the first time i click button to navigate it works fine, but after that when i go back from detail to home and click another item to see the detail, the params on detail screen is not changed (its still the params of the 1st click). Here my code :

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
  key={index}
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('PenghuniScreen', {
      screen: 'DetailPenghuni',
      params: {
        penghuni: item,
      },
    });
  }}></TouchableNativeFeedback>;
```

item is object from map loop . i try to console log using react navigation usefocuseffect and the params not changin after 1st click.

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log('My params:', route.params.penghuni);
      setPenghuni(route.params.penghuni);
      return () => {
        // source.cancel('Api Canceled');
        console.log('tutup detail penghuni');
      };
    }, []),
  );
```

anyone got solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to add the `route` dependency to your `useCallback`, so it is getting the old value.

Try adding `[route]`:

```
React.useCallback(() => {
      console.log('My params:', route.params.penghuni);
      setPenghuni(route.params.penghuni);
      return () => {
        // source.cancel('Api Canceled');
        console.log('tutup detail penghuni');
      };
}, [route]),
```

I suggest you adding the [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) for hooks to your project, to detect missing dependecies.
[image: exhaustive-deps warning]

**Observation**: Why don't you pass these values though the navigation params instead of using `useFocusEffect`?

```
navigation.navigate('DetailPenghuni', { penghuni: item1 }) // item1 press 
navigation.navigate('DetailPenghuni', { penghuni: item2 }) // item2 press
```

If you need to cancel something you can always use the [useEffect clean callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) called automatically when you close a screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `route.params.penghuni` directly instead of setting  `setPenghuni(route.params.penghuni)`

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log('My params:', route.params.penghuni);
      // setPenghuni(route.params.penghuni); 
      return () => {
        // source.cancel('Api Canceled');
        console.log('tutup detail penghuni');
      };
}, [route.params?.penghuni]),
```