# route.params not visible inside useFocusEffect()

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

With React Navigation 5.x, params are [passing back to parent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen) function. Here is the code in parent receiving 2 params `index` and `type`:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native"

export default MyWork = ({navigation, route}) => {
  console.log("route.params :", route.params); //<<==route.params : {"index": 0, "type": "forsale"}}
  ....

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {  
      console.log("in navigation", route.params);  //<<== route.params undefined
      try {
        if (route.params?.index && route.params?.type) {
          updateCnt(route.params.type, route.params.index);
        }
      } catch(err) {

      }
  }, []));
```

However inside the `useFocusEffect`, `route.params` becomes undefined. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to add the `route` dependency to `useCallback`, otherwise it uses the old value (in this case `undefined`) rather than the updated one.

```
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      console.log('in navigation', route.params);
      try {
        if (route.params?.index && route.params?.type) {
          updateCnt(route.params.type, route.params.index);
        }
      } catch (err) {

      }
    }, [route]),
  );
```

A similar question was answered here where you can find more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/64190936/13912074